# Axios formData dont send any data

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to upload a file using Axios but for that I need to use formData, my problem is that when I am using formData the data are not send at all.

Here is my code **without** formData, its working fine all the data are sent :

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: jsonurl,
  data: {
      session_id: '123',
  },
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }
})
.then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // return in console : status 200 and config: data: session_id: "123" ...
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

Same code with formData (no data sent, $_GET['id'] doesnt exist) :

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('session_id', '123');    
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: jsonurl,
  formData,
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }
})
.then((value) => {
  console.log(value); // return in console :  status 200 but config: data: FormData {}
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

No data sent, return in console status 200 but **config: data: FormData {}** (so no data) and on backend $_POST['session_id'] doesnt exist, the form is sent (I get my jsonencode return) but there is no input data.

I dont catch any error either.

Comment: try `data: formData` in axios request

Comment: Yep I tried already, doesnt change anything, wich one is the good syntax btw (data: formData or formData) ? I saw examples with both.

Comment: The [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) only supports a `data` prop (there's no `formData` prop).

Comment: It might be the issue that you are appending `session_id` to formData but check on the server side for `id`.

Comment: @lotype just a typo, I dont get any input on the backend when I am using formData

Comment: why are you seing an `POST` but tryint to acess `$_GET`? sholdnt it be `$_POST`? try `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @Ifaruki just a typo, I am using Input:all() (from Laravel), so its _POST and _GET, as I said the backend work fine, I get everything when I dont use formData but I need it for file upload.

Comment: did you try to dump `$_FILES`? like `var_dump($_FILES)` to see if there is any file

Comment: @Ifaruki I just try simple data for now (session_id), if no data pass, files upload is not going to work anyway, once problem at a time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, my syntax was wrong, here is one who works :

```
var postResults = await axios.post(jsonurl,
formData,
{
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}
)
.then(function(value){
    console.log(value);

    return value;
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```